# Which server framework (or even platform) do I need for a small dev team?

Tags: java, php, frameworks, multiplatform

I want to develop an server/client software of which the clients will be in different Os's.

(Think Mobile phones, tablets, desktop pc's, I even consider this service to connect with asterisk and work with a phone call center).

I'm really searching amongst all the available server frameworks and cannot decide what is the best for my case or whether I even NEED for my specific problem.

Things to consider:

- I need it to be scalable: Initially that server will be accessed through a website but later it will expand and allow people to access it through mobile apps, desktop applications, phone call/sms service, etc..
- Low cost hosting and open source
- Thousands of users to be using that service in the future. (So it must be able to handle this)
- Small dev team (1-3 ppl)
- I've done past projects in C/C++, actionscript, a bit java and a bit php.
- I don't know much about server programming yet (but I'm ok with learning).
- So:

  - it must have an active community and not have died yet.
  - Be as easy as possible to learn.
  - it must already solve the problems of security, packet asynchronism, concatenation 
    for me etc.

Is there such a thing, should I even bother to mess with a framework? What options do I have considering the tools available?  What does the industry use? A list of possible options would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't know much about server programming and want to develop a service for thousands of users!? to be honest - drop that idea

Comment: [Your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325941) was closed for being off topic. This is a very [open ended question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). "client/server" is an extremely broad space. "Easy to learn" depends on the people on your dev team. "Scalable" will be a function of your design (what can and cannot be done in parallel, what must be synchronous or not) and your hosting (do you hit limits of cpu/memory/disk usage). The only real requirement seems to be "Web" = many different HTTP solutions exist.

Comment: Don't be negative with me asking! I created this one because I read in the FAQ that I must not refer to a personal issue I want to solve but rather, on a more broad issue that might help someone else...! and Philipp ,no I'm not dropping the idea.. I had no clue how to create a game 6 months ago and I now I really know how to do so. Stop being negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technology stack which is open source, scales well and has a very active community is:

- Java
- Tomcat Servlet Container
- Spring Framework (with Spring Security)
- Either Spring Web-services or Apache CXF for web service (mobile connections for example)
- JPA (Hibernate) ORM on top of MySQL

There are numerous other projects that sit around these technologies that fulfill various requirements.  I would certainly recommend this as a starting point to your investigation.

Comment: I was looking for a list of tools.. Thank you for your time.